# Is it O(L1 + L2) or O(max(L1, L2))?

Tags: data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

We have two lists of lengths L1 and L2. We have traversed both the lists one after the other. What will be the time complexity of overall operation?

**Is it O(L1 + L2) or O(max(L1, L2))?**
What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

The first one O(L1 + L2) is appropriate.  For instance, in graph algorithms that use V for the number of vertices and E for the number of edges, many operations are expressed in terms of O(V + E) such as a depth first search of the graph.  Of course in this case, E may range from O(V) to O(V^2).  If L1 and L2 are fixed in relation to each other, then O(max(L1, L2)) = O(L1) or O(L2) may be more appropriate.

Comment: I would also think this is more appropriate answer as we dont have to assume any relation between L1 and L2

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two. Without loss of generality, assume L1 = O(L2); if it's not, then L2 = O(L1) and you can just swap the symbols.

O(L1 + L2) = O(2*L2) = O(L2). Similarly, O(max(L1, L2)) = O(L2). So in both cases, the complexity is O(L2).

Comment: @waldol1: either L1 = O(L2) or L2 = O(L1), since O denotes an asymptotic upper bound only.

Comment: That may be true, but we cannot assume symmetry of L1 and L2.  Like I said in my answer, when traversing two variable length lists, whose lengths may not be the same order, then traversing both leads to O(L1 + L2).  Or in the case where the relationships of L1 and L2 are known, then a single O(L1) or O(L2) suffices.